# How can I updateMany mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have three chatrooms and I would like to update the document with MongoDB only if the user matches with the members.user_id. I don't understand, it's updating to all the member's devices the same token. If someone has an idea?

It's my Node.js code :

```
const _id = req.params._id;
                const token = req.body.token;
                const user_id = req.body.user_id;
            
                try{
                    const updateDevice = await ChatRoom.updateMany(
    {"members.$[].user_id" : user_id},
    {$set:{"members.$[].devices":token}})
                    res.send(updateDevice)
                }catch(err){console.log(err)}


    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const chatRoom_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name:{
            type:Array,
            name:String,
        },
        members:{
            user_id:String,
            name:String,
            devices:String,
            type:Array,
            required:true
        },
        lastMessage:{
            content:String,
            createdAt:Date,
            type:Array,
            send_by:String,
            readBy:Array
        }
    }, {
        collection: "chatRoom"
    })
    module.exports = chatRoom =  mongoose.model("ChatRoom", chatRoom_schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the schema there is a object of **members** not an **array of object** so to access the specific elements only **dot(.)** operator is used. If you want to access any element from the array or want to update the specific object value in array of object then **$** is used.

Try this query to solve the problem

```
ChatRoom.updateMany(
    {"members.user_id" : user_id},
    {$set:{"members.devices":token}})
```

Let there be a record like

```
    members=[
       {
        "user_id":"1",
        "name":"DD",
        "type":"ADMIN"
       },
       {
        "user_id":"2",
        "name":"HH",
        "type":"CUSTOMER"
       }
    ]
```

To update the type of user_id(2) from CUSTOMER to ADMIN then **$** operator can be useful.

The query can be

```
    ChatRoom.updateMany({"members.$.user_id" : 2},
    {$set:{"members.$.type":"ADMIN"}})
```

Comment: Hello !! Thanks to you, I got it right . I've done that :
const updateDevice = await ChatRoom.updateMany(
            {"members.user_id" : user_id},
            {$set:{"members.$.devices":token}})
        res.send(updateDevice)


It's now working, really, thank you !!